# How to sort alphanumeric based on number in groovy?

Tags: groovy

How to sort alphanumeric values based on numeric value using groovy ?For example : I have list of values [NAC-1,MAK-4,NAC-5,LOP-2,MAK-3,...]
I want to take highest value from list(NAC-5).Want to sort the list based on numeric value. Please advise.

I was trying below code

```
List1.sort{ a,b ->
def n1 = (a =~ /\d+/)[-1] as Integer
def n2 = (b =~ /\d+/)[-1] as Integer
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may simply be:

```
def l = ['NAC-1','MAK-4','NAC-5','LOP-2','MAK-3',]
l.sort{ a,b -> -(((a =~ /\d+/)[-1] as Integer)  <=> ((b =~ /\d+/)[-1] as Integer))
}
```

Or (easier to read):

```
def l = ['NAC-1','MAK-4','NAC-5','LOP-2','MAK-3',]
l.sort { a, b -> 
    (a,b) = [a, b].collect { (it =~ /\d+/)[-1] as Integer }
    b <=> a
}
```

Or (extremely easy to read, by @dmahapatro):

```
l.sort { - ( it[-1] as Integer ) } // will work for single digit number only
```

Comment: `l.sort { - ( it[-1] as Integer ) }`

Comment: Should probably caveat that with "this will only work if the numbers are all single-digit".